# showing an element if any one of multiple drop down selector is set to anything but 0

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I am a newbie to jquery so wanted some help. Please see some html code.

```
<select name="jj_register_Editor[profile]" id="jj_register_profile">
    <option value="0">None Selected</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="1407">profile 1</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="1485">profile 2</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="1503">profile 3</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="1493">profile 4</option
</select>

<select name="jj_register_Editor[page]" id="jj_register_page">
    <option value="0">None Selected</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="1407">Page 1</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="1485">Page 2</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="1503">Page 3</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="1493">Page 4</option
</select>

<select name="jj_register_Editor[cats]" id="jj_register_cats">
    <option value="0">None Selected</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="1407">Cats 1</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="1485">Cats 2</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="1503">Cats 3</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="1493">Cats 4</option
</select>

<select name="jj_register_Editor[tags]" id="jj_register_tags">
    <option value="0">None Selected</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="1407">sometags 1</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="1485">sometags 2/option>
    <option class="level-0" value="1503">sometags 3</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="1493">sometags 4</option
</select>


<div id="somediv">Some div element</div>
```

I need to show the bottom `div` when any of the above select boxes are loaded with any value other than 
'0'.. ps if all values are 0 then we need to hide the `div`.

PLease see my attempts. This makes sure only one of the select boxes can be selected at once. I want to make sure that if any one of these drop downs has a value other than 0 (on load , not on change) then the "somediv" element is shown.

Obviously this is rubbish, so exscuse my ignorance, but it does most of what I want. The main problem is that I want to make sure that if any of drop the drop downs have a value other than 0 then we need to show the `div` (when the page loads.) I haev worked out how to do this when any of the options are changed.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
    if (jQuery('#jj_register_page').val() != '0'){
        jQuery( ".form-table tr:nth-child(5)" ).show();
    }
    else{
        jQuery( ".form-table tr:nth-child(5)" ).hide();  
    }

    jQuery('#jj_register_page').change(function(){
        jQuery('#jj_register_cats').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        jQuery('#jj_register_tag').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        jQuery('#jj_register_bp').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        if (jQuery(this).val() != '0'){
            jQuery(".form-table tr:nth-child(5)").show(200);
        }
        else{
            jQuery(".form-table tr:nth-child(5)").hide(200);   
        }
    });

    jQuery('#jj_register_cats').change(function(){
        jQuery('#jj_register_page').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        jQuery('#jj_register_tag').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        jQuery('#jj_register_bp').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        if (jQuery(this).val() != '0'){
            jQuery(".form-table tr:nth-child(5)").show(200);
        }
        else{
            jQuery(".form-table tr:nth-child(5)").hide(200);   
        }
    });

    jQuery('#jj_register_tag').change(function(){
        jQuery('#jj_register_page').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        jQuery('#jj_register_cats').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        jQuery('#jj_register_bp').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        //jQuery(".form-table tr:nth-child(5)").css('display', (jQuery(this).val() != '0' ) ? 'block' : 'none');
        if (jQuery(this).val() != '0'){
            jQuery(".form-table tr:nth-child(5)").show(200);
        }
        else{
            jQuery(".form-table tr:nth-child(5)").hide(200);   
        }
    });
    jQuery('#jj_register_bp').change(function(){
        jQuery('#jj_register_page').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        jQuery('#jj_register_cats').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        jQuery('#jj_register_tag').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        if (jQuery(this).val() != '0'){
            jQuery(".form-table tr:nth-child(5)").show(200);
        }
        else{
            jQuery(".form-table tr:nth-child(5)").hide(200);   
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Have you actually tried any jQuery yet?

Comment: Please show what you've done so far.  If nothing, take a look at jquery's `.change()`

Comment: Hi the code I have is not very good, so exscuse my ignorance.

Comment: What is .prop('selectedIndex')? You should use jQuery's .val() instead, and check for 0 (in this case, .val() will return an array, just check if the array length is greater than 1 (which means something other than 0 is selected), and if not, if array[0] == 0

Comment: Hi, I see what you are saying but I need to know if any of the four drop downs have a value other than o. If any ONE of the four does, then I need to show the div.